# Create_Failed S3BatchProcessor, AWS Lambda

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-cdk, amazon-textract

I am running `cdk deploy` in my textract pipline folder for large document processing. However, when i run this porgram I get this error

[The error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ke1j2.png)

```
| CREATE_FAILED        | AWS::Lambda::Function           | S3BatchProcessor6C619AEA
Resource handler returned message: "Specified ReservedConcurrentExecutions for function decreases account's UnreservedConcurrentExecution below its minimum value of [10]. (Service: Lambda, Status Code: 400, Request ID: 7f6d1305-e248-4745-983e-045eccde562d)" (RequestToken: 9c84827d-502e-5697-b023-e
0be45f8d451, HandlerErrorCode: InvalidRequest)
```

Comment: are there other lambda functions in your account. If yes what is their concurrency?

Answer (score 1):

By default AWS will provide with at max `1000` concurrency limit.
In your case, the different concurrencies in all lambdas in your account is exceeding *UnreservedConcurrentExecution Limit of 10* i.e.,

```
1000 - sum all reservedConcurrency in lambdas > 10
```

This is causing deployment failure as you're trying to exceed concurrency limit.

There can be two solutions here:

1. Reduce the reserved concurrency of lambdas so that above equation holds or
2. You can raise the account concurrency limit by contacting aws support. Please refer [this](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/lambda-concurrency-limit-increase/)

Comment: When I run  'cdk deploy'  it creates the necessary lambda function and then destroys the function when the program fails.                                                                                  
Is there way to reduce the reserved concurrency for the overall textract pipeline?         
I don't think I can reduce the concurrecny limit for a lambda function that hasn't been created yet. I put in a request for quota increase as well. Thank you again for your help!